# Sublime Text 3 no longer holds SCSS syntax highlighting

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

My SCSS files keep defaulting to an unfamiliar syntax highlighting for Sublime Text (build 3103).  The [SCSS package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SCSS) was working up until now.

Recently, Sublime Text displayed a message about one of my packages updating & how my display preferences would be corrupted until I reset Sublime.  My sidebar looked weird, so I reset it.  This fixed the sidebar, but every time I open an SCSS file its highlighting is wrong.

**Things I've tried, in various combinations...**

- Remove the SCSS package
- Quit Sublime Text completely
- Delete the `Packages/User/SCSS.sublime-settings` file
- Delete the `Cache/SCSS/` directory
- Reinstall the SCSS package
- Set the syntax automatically with `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as... > SCSS`
- Set the syntax manually with `Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings – More > Syntax Specific – User`

**How my `SCSS.sublime-settings` file appears...**

```js
/// SCSS.sublime-settings
{
  "extensions":
  [
    "scss"
  ]
}
```

#### EDIT

> "... unfamiliar syntax highlighting..."

It is still recognized as an SCSS file (as stated in the bottom right of the editor window).  But the *highlighting* is unfamiliar, as it does not match the highlighting style I have seen for any syntax.

**More details...**

- No color schemes or themes were changed, I quadruple-checked in the settings
- How it happened

  1. I was working with SCSS
  2. The update to build 3103 occurred
  3. I reset Sublime Text
  4. The highlighting broke for SCSS (all of the other syntax highlights seem fine)

The closest thing I have found to an answer (which is also what [style-nes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356245/5071345) referenced) is that the 3103 build added a new syntax definition format called `.sublime-syntax`, which the SCSS probably doesn't account for (looks un-maintained).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "*My SCSS files keep defaulting to an unfamiliar syntax highlighting*"? What syntax is being used instead (you can look in the lower right part of the window to see)? Did you accidentally switch color schemes? Please [edit] your question and add more details to explain the issue, as it is too vague at this point.

Comment: @MattDMo, do you know of a way to update Sublime Text to build 3103 and keep syntax as it previously was? The update destroyed my homebrewed theme.